# Width of the expander header affects the scrollviewer outside

Tags: c#, wpf, styling

The below is my code

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
```

Here I have set the datatemplate for the header of the expander I am using inside the stack Panel

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="titleText">
        <Border Background="Green" Height="24">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                    Width="{Binding
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                    Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,3"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource titleText}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have a scroll viewer for the stack panel

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander IsExpanded="True" x:Name="general" Header="General">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <GroupBox Header="Mode Control">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="RESET"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="MAKEUP" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="POWERDOWN"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Mode Control">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="RESET"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="MAKEUP" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="POWERDOWN"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Mode Control">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="RESET"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="MAKEUP" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="POWERDOWN"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Mode Control">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="RESET"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="MAKEUP" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="POWERDOWN"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Mode Control">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="RESET"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="MAKEUP" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="POWERDOWN"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem here is the scroll bar is not working even when the stack panel's width is more.

I can understand why it happens,because of setting the width of the expander to its parent,so scroll bar is not working

But I want both the scroll bar working and enabled as well as the datatemplate with style for the header

Any one can give solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't work because the width of the expander's header also includes the button used to expand and collapse the control.

Think of it this way: the header area of the control contains two elements side-by-side, the expand/collapse button and the header "content". You are binding the width of the header content part (your `Border` element) to the width of the expander control, but this doesn't subtract the width of the expand/collapse button. Hence your layout breaks.

If the header content part sat *behind* the expand/collapse button then your approach would work, but unfortunately that's not how the default `Expander` control template is designed.

I'm just guessing, but it looks to me like you are simply trying to set the background colour of the expander. Unfortunately, again due to the default control template, this isn't possible:

- if you set the `Background` property of the expander, this *will* change the colour of the header, but it will also change the colour of the content area which probably isn't what you want
- putting another element in the header (such as your `Border`) and attempting to get it to "stretch" to the width of the control (by setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`) won't work either, as the element into which the header is placed is hard-coded in the control template to be left-aligned.

As far as I know, the only way of accomplishing what you want is to write your own control template for the expander and use that instead. You should be able to find some examples of this here on SO or by Googling.